# Low free swap but nothing uses it

Tags: linux, postgresql, swap

We've PostgreSQL 10.3 running on 7.4.1708.
Yesterday, suddenly something claimed swap space about 2.2GB.

I could find only few process and restarted them only got about 200MB.

I've dropped pagecache and set vm.swappiness to 0
But swap did not drop.

I've searched what claimed swap but I could not find.

- free says, 2025MB swap is claimed
- top says nothing claimed swap
- smem says nothing claimed swap

`root@server# free -m
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:        1031502        9793      308314      201749      713394      812428
    Swap:          4095        2025        2070`

`root@server#smem -s swap
178243 root     python /bin/smem -s swap           0     6184     6682    10120
1 root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --        8    16632    17267    20720
7929 root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-jo      108    12624    52410    94280`

`root@server#top -o SWAP
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR   SWAP S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ 
  7929 root      20   0  144380  94436  94148    108 S   0.0  0.0  29:32.52 
     1 root      20   0  206152  20720   5480      8 S   0.0  0.0  61:07.68
     2 root      20   0       0      0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:22.39`

I don't want to swapoff and swapon. Because this is our primary db server, I've heard swapoff could make system unstable.

What should I do, how can I find which process claimed that swap space?

Comment: Possibly related answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479953/how-to-find-out-which-processes-are-using-swap-space-in-linux

Comment: I saw that link you sent and I've already looked at swap usage per process with smem and top. But no process showed up. I post this because of that.